# How to call the category cover image on the tpl file on prestashop.

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Could you tell me how to call the "category cover image" on the tpl file on prestashop 1.6.1.6? I looked for it on the category.php of the classes and I didn't find it.

Comment: There is no get cover function. You can use the id_image and image_dir properties if using category as an object they will be set in the __construct.

Comment: On further inspection I believe image_dir returns the installation dir, not the url. For the img, the default theme uses <img class="replace-2x" src="{$link->getCatImageLink($subcategory.link_rewrite, $subcategory.id_image, 'medium_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$subcategory.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$mediumSize.width}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" />

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : the url of the image is always `https://www.example.com/img/tmp/category_categoryid.jpg`so I took it and `https://www.example.com/img/tmp/category_{$category->id}.jpg`

It works perfectly.